# how do you change directory on the remote server using jsftp in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Can anyone tell me how to change the directory on the remote server using jsftp in node js?

I have tried:

```
Ftp.raw.cd("subfolder",function(err, data) {
    ...
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Object function () { [native code] } has no method 'cd'
...
```

Comment: try `Ftp.raw.cwd("subfolder", cb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running console.log on Ftp.raw shows:

```
{ [Function]
  abor: [Function],
  pwd: [Function],
  cdup: [Function],
  feat: [Function],
  noop: [Function],
  quit: [Function],
  pasv: [Function],
  syst: [Function],
  cwd: [Function],
  dele: [Function],
  list: [Function],
  mdtm: [Function],
  mkd: [Function],
  mode: [Function],
  nlst: [Function],
  pass: [Function],
  retr: [Function],
  rmd: [Function],
  rnfr: [Function],
  rnto: [Function],
  site: [Function],
  stat: [Function],
  stor: [Function],
  type: [Function],
  user: [Function],
  xrmd: [Function],
  opts: [Function],
  chmod: [Function],
  size: [Function] }
```

The issue being that cd is not a valid function, hence the error. You should probably use `Ftp.raw.cwd` instead to set the current directory. If you wish to go up one level, the `cdup` function seems to be implemented for that purpose.